# when I'm accessing website that I deployed in Netlify it don't show any content

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web-deployment, netlify, netlify-form

I hosted my react js webesite using Netlify, but when I hosted it that time there was no error in deployment time, but when I'm trying to access it so I'm getting only blank page with no content.

```
This is my website URL, https://dreamy-lily-038fc8.netlify.app/
```

[image: netlify screenshot]

this is the production deploy and I don't think there is any error..
So Please guide me what I need to do now..?

Comment: You are probably serving the wrong directory as your build directory, how is it called the directory of your build. What did you set in Netlify settings as build directory ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara I've used main branch where all code are there. but Base directory - Not set
Build command - npm run build
Publish directory - build
Deploy log visibility - Logs are public
Builds - Active

Comment: You can try to manually upload your build folder to check if it's a build issue. If you are trying to build directly on Netlify server after git push to main branch, you need to set correctly the build command and the build folder pathinside Netlify settings page, Site settings, build & deploy tab.

If you are using create-react-app, they will be respectiveley:
`npm run build` and build

Comment: @CesarePolonara when I tried to upload it manually then it is working fine and my website launched but when I'm doing it with in sync git hub it will not work yeah I checked everything is correct only but what I will get error is ```Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non zero exit code 2``` . do you have any idea like why it is coming like this?

Comment: That happens if you have any warning in your react app, by default Netlify won't build if you have warnings if you have Netlify env variable CI=true .
You can change Netify env variables in your app setting, to CI=false . That should fix it.